# How to get each value of an array individually and run a function on it with an unknown number of values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, toggle

I'm quite new to jQuery and I am having a hard time with getting all of the values from my array individually and running `.toggle()` on them.

For each checkbox I have, I have a `<div>` element with an ID identical to the value of the respective checkbox. I want to allow users to check as many checkboxes as they would like, and for each checkbox and piece of content will be toggled.

How can I achieve this? As you can see by the output in the console, it outputs the entire array `x` the number of checkboxes that are ticked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ghb_toggle').hide()
    $("#GHB_Form").on('submit', function() {
        var allVals = [];
        $.each($("input[name='GHB_checkbox']:checked"), function() {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        $(allVals).each(function() {
            console.log(allVals);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="GHB_Form" onsubmit="return false;">
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#design-for-your-climate">
   <label>Design for your climate</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#placement-considerations">
   <label>Placement considerations</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#overall-aesthetics">
   <label>Overall aesthetics</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#performance">
   <label>Performance</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#foundations">
   <label>Foundations</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#flooring">
   <label>Flooring</label><br>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="ghb_toggle" id="design-for-your-climate">Design for your climate</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="placement-considerations">Placement considerations</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="overall-aesthetics">Overall aesthetics</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="performance">Performance</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="foundations">Foundations</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="flooring">Flooring</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` loop will expose an index (nth of element in the current loop) and the value of the current index. The latter will be your selector to toggle the element.

```
$(allVals).each(function(index, value) {
  $(value).show();
});
```

Before doing so do hide all toggles again to reset them. Otherwise they will stay visible when you submit more than once.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ghb_toggle').hide()
  $("#GHB_Form").on('submit', function() {
      var allVals = [];
      $.each($("input[name='GHB_checkbox']:checked"), function() {
          allVals.push($(this).val());
      });

      // First hide everything again.
      $('.ghb_toggle').hide()

      $(allVals).each(function(i, value) {
          $(value).show();
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="GHB_Form" onsubmit="return false;">
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#design-for-your-climate">
   <label>Design for your climate</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#placement-considerations">
   <label>Placement considerations</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#overall-aesthetics">
   <label>Overall aesthetics</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#performance">
   <label>Performance</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#foundations">
   <label>Foundations</label><br>
   <input name="GHB_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="#flooring">
   <label>Flooring</label><br>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="ghb_toggle" id="design-for-your-climate">Design for your climate</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="placement-considerations">Placement considerations</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="overall-aesthetics">Overall aesthetics</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="performance">Performance</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="foundations">Foundations</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="flooring">Flooring</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I did plan on hiding all of my elements before firing the function each time. My problems are solved :)